# making API calls in angular redux app

Tags: json, angular, api, redux

I want to fetch json data from a server in a basic angular-redux todo app.Also please do explain how the data flow happens from the store.If u can kindly refer any blogs on the matter,it would be great.I could not make a lot of sense from ng2-redux or ngrx.Thank you in advance.

Comment: basically you dispatch an action and the action will do the api call. Once its done it will then dispatch the data to your reducer.

Comment: As far as Angular is two-way data binding it does not need Redux. [Here is a piece of code to demonstrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287964/why-should-i-use-redux-in-angular-as-far-as-angular-is-two-way-data-binding).

Answer (score 0):

You should make API calls in [Middleware](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html). Read this [book](https://leanpub.com/redux-book), its free, it will clear most of your doubts, it did it for me when I started learning.

Answer (score 0):

You should make API calles (as knowen as side effects) with a middleware like Epic.
Let's considere an example of todo app that you need to get the todos from the server:

```
const BASE_URL = "https://some-server/api/";

@Injectable()
export class TodoEpics implements EpicMiddleware {

    constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) {
    }

    @dispatch()
    startLoading() {
        return changeTodoStatus("loading");
    }

    getTodosEpic = (action$: ActionsObservable<GetTodosAction>, state$: StateObservable<AppState>): Observable<Action> => {
        return action$.pipe(
            ofType(todoConstants.GET_TODOS),
            tap((action) => this.startLoading()),
            mergeMap(action => this.httpService.get<GetTodosResponse>(`${BASE_URL}/todos`).pipe(
                map((response) => getTodosSucceeded(response.items)),
                catchError(error => of(getTodosFailed(error)))
            ))
        );
    }

    getEpics(): Epic[] {
        return [
            this.getTodosEpic
        ];
    }
}
```

and in the main store module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgReduxModule, NgRedux, DevToolsExtension } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { AppState } from './models';
import { rootReducer } from './reducers';
import { TodoEpics } from "../todo-list/todo-list-state-management/epics";
import { combineEpics, createEpicMiddleware } from "redux-observable";
import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

@NgModule({
    imports: [NgReduxModule],
    providers: [
        TodoEpics
    ]
})
export class StoreModule {
    constructor(private store: NgRedux<AppState>, private todoEpics: TodoEpics) {
        const rootEpic = combineEpics(
            ...this.todoEpics.getEpics()
        );
        const middelwares = [epicMiddleware]
        const devMiddelwares = [...middelwares, createLogger()];
        const prodMiddelwares = [...middelwares];

        store.configureStore(
            rootReducer,
            environment.production ? prodMiddelwares : devMiddelwares);

        epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic)
    }
}
```

a complete example can be found here: [Todo app using angular-redux, redux-observable and epics](https://github.com/IsraelZablianov/angular-redux-example)